# How does a=a++ work in java

Tags: java

Recently I came across this piece of Java code:

```
int a=0;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    a=a++;
}
System.out.println(a);
```

The value printed for 'a' is 0. However in case of C, the value for 'a' comes out to be 100.

I am not able to understand why the value is 0 in case of Java.

Comment: "However in case of C" - huh? Oh, C language.. I am pretty sure you need a sequence point in there for it to work

Comment: No, in C it's undefined behavior.

Comment: The sequence points are well defined in Java.. so you are just reassigning 0 all the time.. cool

Comment: In C also it will be 0, isn't it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
a = a++;
```

starts with incrementing `a`, and then reverting `a` to the old value as `a++` returns the not incremented value.

In short it does nothing in Java. If you want to increment, use only the postfix operator like this :

```
a++;
```

Comment: Controversial answer already

Comment: Yeah lol, pretty good.

Comment: Dang, the rapid downvotes and upvotes :D

Comment: It's called the [Postfix Increment Operator](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap39/ch39_3.html)

Comment: First time I've seen an answer go to 7, then 4, then past 7 again.

Comment: I've always read `a = a++` to mean "assign current value of a to a, then increment the resulting value of a so that a is ultimately one higher than before". Why on Earth is it designed so that it means "put aside the old value of a, then increment a, then assign the old value of a back to a so that we end up where we started anyhow". Seems ridiculous that Java runs that way. (I know that you'd never need to use `a = a++` but it still seems a cack-handed way for the JVM to interpret this statement.)

Comment: If you look at the output of `javap -c` you can see what is going on.  `var=var++;` compiles to `iload_1; iinc 1, 1; istore_1` while `var=++var;` compiles to `iinc 1, 1; iload_1; istore_1`;  In the first example the value to be assigned is loaded before the increment, so the store operation destroys the effect of incrementing.  In the second example the value for the assignment is loaded after the incrementing.  `var++;` doesn't load or store because `iinc 1, 1` by itself updates the value in place in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

a++ is a post increment, so a is assigned the value of a (always 0), and the ghost variable of a is incremented afterwards making no difference to the real a and no result being saved.
As a result, a is always assigned to 0, thus the code does nothing

Answer (score -1):

Because:

```
a = a++;///will assign 'a' to 'a' then increment 'a' in the next step , but from the first step 'a' is '0' and so on
```

To get 100 you can do Like this:

```
a = ++a;////here the 'a' will be increment first then will assign this value to a so a will increment in every step
```

or

```
a++;////here the increment is the only operation will do here
```